# Text from dashboard not showing sub-property from payload

Tags: node.js, text, npm, dashboard, node-red

I've been using [dashboard's](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-dashboard) **Text** node to show `msg.payload.time` in web-ui without any issues. However, I recently updated my dashboard to version **2.3.10** and now my **Text** node is not showing anything.

This is my data model:

```
{
  "topic": "agent/last-download",
  "payload": {
      "time": "2017-05-15 16:48:43",
      "name": "dummy name",
      "path": "/mnt/externalDrive/dummyFolder"
  },
  "qos": 0,
  "retain": true,
  "_topic": "agent/last-download",
  "_msgid": "1c476895.e3b897"
}
```

This is how I'm setting **Value format**:

```
{{msg.payload.time}}
```

When I output `msg.payload.time` to **debug** node, it works fine. Or if I set `msg.payload` to **Text** then it also works but dumps complete payload as text - which is not my requirement. I've also tested setting `msg.topic`, `msg._msgid` and etc. to **Text** and they all work fine.

Any idea why the behavior is changed? or Is there any other way to retrieve payload's sub values?

Comment: This appears to be a regression in behaviour. Will investigate.

Comment: Issue raised: https://github.com/node-red/node-red-dashboard/issues/230

Comment: @knolleary thanks. Did you test that it's working till 2.3.9?

Comment: Yes - worked up to 2.3.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression in behaviour in the 2.3.10.

Until a fix is released, you can add a `Change` node ahead of the `ui_text` node to move `msg.payload.time` to `msg.payload` and the value will be displayed.